# Control executing of hidden subreports inside tablix (SSRS)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I am using SSRS2008R2, On my main report there is tablix inside tablic there is row (merged cells) which contain sub report. Subreport is initially hidden and toggled by other cell. 
[image]
When I preview my report it is working fine, I can show and hide sub report clicking on "referat" cell.
But my problem is that for every row inside tablix SSRS generating subreport, That task take a lot of time. I want to make my hiden reports do not contain data and do not call SQL during first execution of report when they are hidden. I want to subreport do SQL call just before user expand (show). [I know that I should pass different params to sub report so it can realize to do or not calling sql (sprocs).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139869/hiding-sub-report-in-ssrs-based-on-parameter-and-not-executing-the-stored-proce)  .
But I do not know how to pass that parameter to subreport, or how to check is something hidden or not so i can change my param to subreport.
[image: Am I setting params at wrong plase]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Value of the parameter is not recalculated when you click on "referat" and the sub-report becomes visible. In other words, all sub-reports are run up front regardless of whether or not they are hidden. My suggestion would be to use linked reports instead. Under the Action section on a textbox properties you can select "Go to report". This may not be as visually appealing, but the sub-report will only be run when it is specifically requested.