# Can we run SSRS sub reports conditionally?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a requirement to run the sub report based on the parameter value. If the user has selected the parameter value other than the expected, the sub report should not run.This is possible if I modify my stored procedure. But I do not have access to modify the stored procedure. This has to be done only from reporting side.

Please give me suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set the hidden property of the subreport to hide the subreport.

Comment: Hiding is not my problem. I am able to hide the sub report. But I do not want to run that report from back end. Hiding the report will not stop the report execution.

Comment: You might want to run the report from SSIS using C# based on your condition.

Comment: We are not using SSIS. Is there any other way to achieve this in SSRS ?

Comment: You could achieve this if you used the SSRS api, however, you would be reinventing the wheel from  UI perspective. If customization is worth it then  it may be your only alternative. The only Report Builder solution that would come close would be a "Navigate To" url or a major javascript kludge that intercepts the request and re-issues it based on your custom action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding Sub report in SSRS based on Parameter (and not executing the Stored Procedure)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139869/hiding-sub-report-in-ssrs-based-on-parameter-and-not-executing-the-stored-proce)

Comment: @Jim: This idea is good. But I do not have access to the Database to create or modify the stored procedure.