# SSRS report objects rendering

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a `SSRS` report which contain two `Tablix` objects with different format, one for horizontal and another one is vertical. Both are using the same procedure. The objects are hiding based on **one report parameter** what the user selecting "Horizontal/Vertical".

My question is that when the user selecting one format and viewing the report, both the objects will render the same time or only one based on the selection ?

Comment: I don't know the tecnichal answer but you could do this simple test: if REMOVING one Tablix increase rendering speed then reporting services render both object even if one is hidden.

Comment: that i tried. But not feel any big difference. technically is there any difference ?

Answer (score 1):

Some processing occurs, but not all.

I believe any report processing (calculations) will still be executed even when an element is invisible - [see Adriaan Stander's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139869/hiding-sub-report-in-ssrs-based-on-parameter-and-not-executing-the-stored-proce)

If you inspect the HTML that is generated you will see that the HTML from the invisible elements is not there.  From my experience with .Net and the visible/invisible setting I believe this would avoid the HTML processing both on the server side (the HTML is never generated) and on the browser side (there isn't any extra HTML to display).

Basically, any caluclations (SUM, AVG, etc) will still be executed, but the actual HTML rendering will not happen.